# Access a specific table depending on a variable in lua

Tags: lua

Hello I have a little problem with lua. I want to access one of the tables containing the route information depending on the route variable defined on the start of the script. But everytime I run the program I always get nil as an answer. Does anybody know how to fix that?

```
route = 1

local eastCityRoute = {
    {name = "ecr-stop1"},
    {name = "ecr-stop2"},
    {name = "ecr-stop3"},
}

local westCityRoute = {
    {name = "wcr-stop1"},
    {name = "wcr-stop2"},
    {name = "wcr-stop3"},
}

routes = {}
routes[1] = eastCityRoute
routes[2] = westCityRoute

print(routes[route][name])
```

Comment: `print(routes[route][name])` should be `print(routes[route][1].name)` where 1 is your first stop. if you expect `name` to return the string `eastCityRoute` then you would need to define the route in the table like this `routes[1] = {route = eastCityRoute, name = "eastCityRoute"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
local eastCityRoute = {
    {name = "ecr-stop1"},
    {name = "ecr-stop2"},
    {name = "ecr-stop3"},
}
```

is short for

```
 local eastCityRoute = {
    [1] = {["name"] = "ecr-stop1"},
    [2] = {["name"] = "ecr-stop2"},
    [3] = {["name"] = "ecr-stop3"},
 {
```

Let's look at your remaining code:

You create a global table `routes` and store two tables `eastCityRoute` and `westCityRoute` in it.

```
routes = {}
routes[1] = eastCityRoute
routes[2] = westCityRoute
```

Now you try this:

```
print(routes[route][name])
```

`route` is `1` so `routes[route]` is equivalent to `routes[1]` which resolves to `eastCityRoute`.

But `eastCityRoute[name]` is equal to `eastCityRoute[nil]`. As `eastCityRoutes` does not have a metatable with a proper `__index` metavalue `eastCityRoute[nil]` resolves to `nil`.

`eastCityRoute[name]` is not the same as `eastCityRoute["name"]`!!!
In one case you index with a variable and in the other case you index with a literal string.

Please read the Lua Reference Manual.